# Control Template used in Code Behind to add dynamically to a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following ControlTemplate in my /Themes/Generic.xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GroupList" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
            <Expander.Header>
                <Label Style="{DynamicResource headline3}" FontWeight="Light" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1">TEst group</Label>
            </Expander.Header>
            <ListBox x:Name="lstBoxContacts" Height="auto" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" PreviewDragOver="lstBoxContacts_PreviewDragOver"  Drop="lstBoxContacts_Drop" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Fullname}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu >
                        <MenuItem Header="Send Message" Command="local:CustomCommands.cmdMessageWrite"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Show Details" Command="local:CustomCommands.cmdContactDetails"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="local:CustomCommands.cmdContactDelete"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            </ListBox>
        </Expander>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

This should give me an expander with a Listbox in it. To which I can pass a `ObservableCollection<User>` object, that is than being displayed (Only the Fullname attribute of the user).

In my MainWindow.xaml I have a Stackpanel named "stkpContactsAndGroups" to which I would like to add Expanders programmatically and dynamically.

The contents come from an API call (Which all works).

From what I have seen I should work with Template.FindName. However, when I supply the origin where said template can be found VS bucks me.

```
Expander grp = (Expander)Template.FindName("GroupList", new Generic());
stkpContactsAndGroups.Children.Add(grp);
```

It cannot convert Generic() to FrameworkElement. Am I missing the point here?

Comment: Don't you want to add the `Custom Control` to your `StackPanel` rather than the `ControlTemplate` (of the Custom Control)

Comment: @SWilko I am not that good with WPF, I am not sure that I fully understand the consequences of said action. I thought the easiest solution would be to have a template of a control, to which I can add data and than add the entire thing to my StackPanel.

Comment: Is Generic in a row 'new Generic()' a ResourceDictionary declared /Themes/Generic.xaml?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[FrameworkTemplate.FindName](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/e5c8679caf5f914f.html) method helps you to find an element inside template if this template is applied to templated parent. In you case you'd better use the [Application.FindResource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,82efec2d60365127) method, create new Expander, apply template using the `Expander.Template` property and after this add this expander to the `StackPanel.Children` collection